# Line-Height does not match the font-size

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-size

When I have two line of text with different font-size, they overlap.
Look at this example :
http://jsfiddle.net/3WcMG/1/

All the 'j' and 'g'  are hiding the to of the second line. It does that with all main fonts.

Why Does it acts like that? What can I do to avoid that?

EDIT: I know what's 'em' means, I know how to use the margins, I know how to increase the line height, I know what is the effect of the reset css of JSFiddle and that is not my question. My question is: Why the bottom of the 'j' is out of the box of the text? It looks like if I put negative margin-top on the second line (except that I haven't, it looks like that by default).
Is there a way to make the font fit in the box.

EDIT2: It seems that it is a browser issue! I am on chrome 21.0 on Mac and I see that :
[image: screenshot]

Comment: if you uncheck the `Normalized CSS` check box in left menu of `jsfiddle.net` and update the fiddle you can see the result like this: http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/3WcMG/2/

Comment: This is due to [CSS Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Comment: Give your `<p>` some top margins to avoid sticking two `<p>` tags

Comment: See an [example](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/3WcMG/9/) with a `top-margin`

Answer (score 23, accepted):

1em is equal to 1 times the number of pixels in a font size. So if your `font-size` is 60px, 1em = 60px. If it is 14px, 1em = 14px, and so on. Setting the `line-height` to 1em makes it equal to 1 times the number of pixels.

There may be some confusion because the default line-height set by the user agent stylesheet is usually somewhere around 1.5em, so a 12px `font-size` would result in an 18px `line-height`.

> **em unit**
>   Equal to the computed value of the ‘font-size’ property of the
>   element on which it is used

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#font-relative-lengths
See also: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#length-units

Based on this, your original example is exactly what I would expect to see. For reference, here is what I see in Chrome:

[image]

Your first line is 60px tall, but the *computed value* (W3's term) of the second is 14px (dictated by the class applied to it). Both have a `line-height` of 1em. Thus, the `line-heights` are 60px and 14px respectively. Since that is the same as the font sizes, the two lines touch (this can vary from font to font).

If you are seeing overlapping behavior, that's a different problem.

To change the behavior, you can use a different line-height, padding, margin, etc. As a side note, [rem units](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#font-relative-lengths) may be more intuitive though [support is lacking](http://caniuse.com/rem) in older browsers.

For an overview of CSS units, see: http://css-tricks.com/css-font-size/

### Fonts not aligned with edges of box

*Updated Question/Problem*

[image]

With regards to the updated question, see: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#propdef-font-size which states that:

> Note that certain glyphs may bleed outside their EM box.

This happened in varying degrees with different fonts that I tried (some bleed both X/Y, some in one direction, some not at all).

I'm not sure there is any way to change this behavior, especially since each browser may use a different algorithm for anti aliasing which can slightly alter the edge of the character.

I *think* `line-box-contain: glyph` may be relevant, but I only see it mentioned in an editor's draft and I'm sure browser support is absent/inconsistent.

http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-linebox/#line-box-contain

Comment: I would generally recommend avoiding citing unstable EDs unless they're the only available or most relevant resource. Consider the less often changed WD http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#font-relative-lengths or better yet the stable recommendation http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/syndata.html#length-units Although em units are probably not going to change in forever, it's still a good idea to link to resources that are more stable :)

Comment: Updated to use your links. Thanks.

Comment: I understand what em means. The thing is that the font seems to be bigger than 60px since it overlaps the second line. I have edited my post.

Comment: @tibo - sorry for the tutorial then...it wasn't clear from your first post what you wanted. The rendering seems to vary based on fonts; some render slightly vertically outside the box, some horizontally. I'm not sure if there is a better explanation than the font sizes don't exactly conform to the box they are supposed to (doing a little research).

Comment: @TimMedora Thanks for your updates, It seems to be a browser system issue, maybe on mac the font is a bit different and overlaps... That sucks! :(

Comment: @tibo - your CSS would pick Helvetica on a Mac, which probably has a different box than Arial (which would be picked by most PCs, and why I didn't see the problem). Trebuchet MS actually was the best for me on the PC (fully contained by the box). It's a combination of font definition and browser rendering.

Comment: @TimMedora - Thanks for your answers, It seems that there is no magic trick like "font-rendering: fit-em-box;"...

Answer (score 1):

Increase the line height in your CSS

**line-height: 2em;** (From 1 to 2em)

Which is in the *p* element.

Answer (score 0):

You can give your "test" class line-height or margin-top whatever you feel comfortable with.

```
.test{
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height:18px;
}
```

Comment: That does not solve my problem. I need the font to be exactly in the em-box, if I correct for chrome on mac, the line-height will be too big for other platform (chrome on windows, or firefox on mac for example)

Comment: maybe you can try giving margin-top to the class test.

http://jsfiddle.net/3WcMG/12/

Answer (score 0):

The default line height is relative size, 150% of the font size in a p for example.  If you change line height using em or %, the browsers will interpret that as "em/% compared to the font size."

http://jsfiddle.net/P7LaP/

```
<div class="small">
    <p>Normal pq</p><br/>
    <p class="short">Short pq</p><br/>
    <p class="tall">Tall pq</p><br/>
</div>
<div class="normal">
    <p>Normal pq</p><br/>
    <p class="short">Short pq</p><br/>
    <p class="tall">Tall pq</p><br/>
</div>
<div class="large">
    <p>Normal pq</p><br/>
    <p class="short">Short pq</p><br/>
    <p class="tall">Tall pq</p><br/>
</div>
```

The example has three sets of three p tags with normal height, short, and tall.  While the three sets are the font size.

```
p {
    color: ffffff;
    background: #777777;
}
.short { line-height: 1em; }
.tall { line-height: 2em; }
.small { font-size: 8px; }
.normal { font-size: 16px; }
.large { font-size: 32px; }
```

I hope this helps.  I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but it looks like you should just delete the line-height line from your stylesheet.