# How to Align two p elements displayed inline with different font-size at top?

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I have to inline p elements that have a different font size and want to align them at the top, so their edges matches.

how is this accomplished?

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {border:0.1em red solid; width:100%; padding:5em;}
p {display:inline; vertical-align:top}
.big {font-size:9em; }
.text {font-size:2em; }
.container{height:15em;}
</style>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Text Align</title>
</head>

<body>

<p class="big">x</p><p class="text"> HELLO WORLD</p>


</body>
</html>
```

Update:

Here's the code in a more real world example. While adjusting the line-height works, I have trouble getting them to the upper edge of the footer container.

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {border:0.1em red solid; width:600px; padding:1em; }
 p {display:inline-table; vertical-align:top; padding:0em; margin:0em; background-color:red;}
.big {font-size:9em; line-height:35px; padding:0em;}
.text {font-size:2em;}
.footer {background-color:green; padding:0em; line-height:1.7em; height:auto; overflow:hidden;}
.area {background-color:yellow; height:500px; margin-bottom:1em; padding:0em;}
</style>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Text Align</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="area">
</div>
<div class="footer" >
<div style="margin:5em auto; display:table;">
<p class="big">x</p>
<p class="text"> HELLO WORLD</p>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: They _are_ both aligned to the top of the line box - give them a background, and you will see it. The problem here are the line heights, plus the fact that x of course is much smaller than those uppercase letters in the other paragraph. Give the first p a line-height of about .3, or the second one one of 5, and you will get closer(!) to what you probably want to achive.

Answer (score 0):

As You can not auto adjust it with CSS i recommend you the manual adjustment.

For more details [on the reason see this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11857786/6082645)

Use `line-height: 49px;` or `line-height: .35em;` to match these `p` elements

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {border:0.1em red solid; width:100%; padding:5em;}
p {display:inline; vertical-align:top}
.big {font-size:9em; line-height: 49px; }
.text {font-size:2em; }
.container{height:15em;}
</style>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Text Align</title>
</head>

<body>

<p class="big">x</p><p class="text"> HELLO WORLD</p>


</body>
</html>
```

**For Update:-**

Add `margin-top:0;` to the `.text` and `padding:0em 1em 1em 1em;` at `.big`. because the `line-height` affects the height of `.big`

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {border:0.1em red solid; width:600px; padding:1em; }
 p {display:inline-block; vertical-align:top;}
.big {font-size:9em; padding-top:0em; margin:0em; line-height:0.35em}
.text {font-size:2em;margin-top:0;}
.footer {background-color:green; overflow:hidden; padding:0em 1em 1em 1em;}
.area {background-color:yellow; height:500px; margin-bottom:1em; padding:0em;}
</style>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Text Align</title>
</head>

<body>
<div class="area">
</div>
<div class="footer" >
<p class="big">x</p>
<p class="text"> HELLO WORLD</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yaah there is no other way. because if it is a top fault you could adjust with some javascript. as this is a `line-height` can only be manually adjusted i guess. For the reason [see this link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11857786/6082645)

Comment: thanks, but how do I get both to the upper edge of an container div? I updated the question to show what I mean.

adjusting the line-height works great, but it pushes both elements too far down.

Comment: I have added a new snippet. and stick to `.35em` i feel it to be equal.

Comment: I update my second code block again a little, what I noticed is, that even with your second solution it only works in chorme and safari, but not in firefox. thanks for your patience